# PHP CGI for apache virtual host

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, cgi, php

I'm using PHP5.3 as module for Apache2.2(Windows). For one virtual host i need use PHP4 as CGI for .php files.
This is my config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "E:\projects\php\wp\dev"
ServerName wp.dev4

AddHandler php4-script .php
Action php4-script "E:\server\bin\php-4.4.9\php.exe"
<Directory "E:\projects\php\wp\dev">
  Options ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But I get error

> The requested URL
>   /server/bin/php-4.4.9/php.exe/test.php
>   was not found on this server.

What's the problem?

Comment: How does test.php related to what you're doing?

Comment: Im just runing http://wp.dev4/test.php.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a Directory block to give permissions to access the directory your PHP CGI is in: `E:\server\bin\php-4.4.9`